# Callback to Async Await - How to make it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have code like:

```
const myImage = document.querySelector('img');

const myRequest = new Request('flowers.jpg');

fetch(myRequest).then((response) => {
  console.log(response.type); // returns basic by default
  response.blob().then((myBlob) => {
    const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
    myImage.src = objectURL;
  });
});
```

How can I change it to async await? like

```
const myImage = document.querySelector('img');

const myRequest = new Request('flowers.jpg');

const response = await fetch(myRequest)
  console.log(response.type); 
  const blob = await response.blob()
    const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob); -> what am I doing wrong here?
    myImage.src = objectURL;
```

when I try to await response.blob() I get ->

```
Argument of type 'Blob' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BlobPart[]'.
  Type 'Blob' is missing the following properties from type 'BlobPart[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 27 more
```

Comment: Works in Chrome. Haven't tested anything else, though.

Comment: This is TypeScript, it's not related to async/await

Comment: By the way, the two codes aren't equivalent. They would be if you wrote `return response.blob().then(...`

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps.

```js
const myImage = document.querySelector('img');

const myRequest = (myImage) => {

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (myImage.src !== '') {
        resolve(console.log(`${myImage}`));
    }
  });
  
}

const process = async () => {
  const response = await myRequest('flowers.jpg');
  console.log(response.type);
  const blob = await response.blob()
  const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  myImage.src = objectURL;
}
process();
```